# How can I search the Exchange Global Address Book by phone number?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a phone number, and I want to find the name of the person who lists that number in the Outlook Exchange Global Address Book at work.

If I use the More Columns option, no results are returned. If I use the Advanced Find window, there is no option for phone number.

I use Outlook 2007 as my client. I also have an iPhone.

Is there some other option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be possible to use a Search in the Active Directory, itself.

Can you open "Active Directory Users and Computers" in your Domain?  There you can choose at 'Advanced' the Field "Phone" and search there.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work. For bonus points, what if I'm on a computer that isn't a member of the domain?

Comment: I think it would not possible to search in the Domain if you don't have a User-Account in the Domain.

Comment: I mean the computer is not joined to the domain, such as my home computer. I can always fire up the VPN and use RDP to connect to a computer in the office, but sometimes I don't feel like finding the authentication card. Thanks for the reply regardless.

Comment: quick shortcut to that dialog -> Run (Win+R) `rundll32 dsquery.dll,OpenQueryWindow`

Comment: "Telephone" for me - there's no way to search all the phone number fields - and I had to get the number in exactly the same format as it was in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has [`ldapsearch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) you can run the following command (just replace the square brackets with the correct info):

```
ldapsearch -b "CN=Users,DC=[company],DC=com" \
-h [ldapserver.example.com] -x \
-D "[DOMAIN]\[username]" \
-w [password] \
"(telephoneNumber=[321-645-7890])"
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a phone number, I recommend using OCS/Lync/Skype for business client as your search tool. Try searching using just the last 4 digits as there is no enforced data standard for entering this information. Search under the contacts tab, and if this number is in the system you should see a match come up.

Answer (score 0):

I selected all the contacts from the global list and added them all to my personal contact list.. took about 5 Min to select 1000 employees and 10 minutes to add them because of the thinking time from the pc

Comment: I think there were about 50k entries at this organization. But something to keep in mind if you have a smaller group.